# Setting up Knockd issues

Tags: ubuntu-server, ufw, knockd

*I asked this question on security overflow last week, however there were no responses, so I am hoping that you can help here. The question is below:*

So i'm busy setting up a knockd service on a VM to enable SSH login when the correct sequence of ports are "knocked on" using knockd and ufw.

The issue that I am currently having is that when the correct sequence of ports are selected, the user.rules for ufw is not able to write the new rule to a file.

I have tried using chmod 777 on all files within /etc/ufw as a test, however the file is still not writable.

The output for /etc/ufw/user.rules is as follows:

```
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/after6.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user6.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user6.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/applications.d is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user.rules is world writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: WARN: /etc/ufw/user.rules is group writable!
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: ERROR: '/etc/ufw/user.rules' is not writable
Jun 14 13:13:31 Pop knockd[4780]: openSSH: command returned non-zero status code (1)
```

The knockd file is shown in the code block below:

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[openSSH]
        sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = ufw allow 22/tcp
        tcpflags    = syn

[closeSSH]
        sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
        seq_timeout = 5
        command     = ufw delete allow 22/tcp
        tcpflags    = syn
```

The output for /etc/default/knockd is shown below:

```
# control if we start knockd at init or not
# 1 = start
# anything else = don't start
# PLEASE EDIT /etc/knockd.conf BEFORE ENABLING
START_KNOCKD=1

# command line options
KNOCKD_OPTS="-i enp0s3"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have found a small work around using IP tables instead of ufw, however another issues has arisen as shown here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882062/knockd-issues-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1]

Answer (score 5):

First heed the warning and reset permission to all files you changed. Having write permissions for all users on your firewall rules isn't a good idea. That is do:

```
chmod -R ga-w /etc/ufw
```

Then disable (comment out or set explicit to off) ProtectSystem directive at knockd.service file (found in /lib/systemd/system/ folder).

If this works, reset it to full and put below it

```
ReadWritePaths=-/etc/ufw/
```

ProtectSystem=full mounts ro /usr, /boot and /etc for processes invoked by the unit excluding directories specified in ReadWritePaths.

If running, before restarting the service do

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I have hit the same problem with a knockd /etc/ufw/user.rules not writeable error.  The knock packets show up in syslog and the ufw insert 1 ... command is attempted.  My current best guess at the cause is the cgroups system.

Using iptables commands instead of ufw commands in /etc/knockd.conf works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but solved it by cleaning out both ip4 and ip6 tables.
In one error message it said that 'xtable' was locked by another process.

```
ufw disable
iptables -F
iptables -X
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X
ufw enable
```

try knocking
and then check

```
service knockd status
```